# DI multiple implementation on single interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have multiple concrete implementations on a single interface. I have registered that in to ASP.NET core DI as below

```
services.AddTransient<EmailService>();
services.AddTransient<SmsService>();
services.AddTransient<Func<MessageType, IMessageService>>(serviceProvider => key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case MessageType.Email:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<EmailService>();
        case MessageType.Sms:
            return serviceProvider.GetService<SmsService>();
        default:
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }
});
```

then i inject `Func<MessageType, IMessageService> serviceAccessor` to constructor

when i request specific implementation `serviceAccessor(MessageType.Sms)` throws an exception

> Activated Event   Time    Duration    Thread Exception thrown:
>   'System.ObjectDisposedException' in
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll ("Cannot access a
>   disposed object.") Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException'
>   in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll ("Cannot access a
>   disposed object.") Hyperlink: Activate Historical
>   Debugging 8.97s   [428]
>   WorkPool-Session#2:Connection(3a5aaef7-e40f-4607-9d12-eacbd0dd5f6d,amqp://localhost:5672)

what was the issue ?

Comment: Which DI container you are using?

Comment: ASP.NET Core default DI container

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Problem becuase in your implementation class was call to the IServiceProvider which will be dispose after the factory of the of the DI. Maybe it’s an issue of the latest if .Net Core I faced the same here.

And for the multiple implementations of the interface. I think better will be

```
Interface IMessage<T> 
Class MailMessage : IMessage<MessageType>
Services.AddTransient<IMessage<MessageType>, MailMessage>()
```